# How to make method not require mutable self for locked Mutex?

Tags: mutex, rust

Acessing a field of a struct for reading 
[rust playpen](http://is.gd/EzyKhK):

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
#[deriving(Show)]
struct Test{
    a: uint,
}
impl Test{
    fn new() -> Test{
        Test { a: 0}
    }
    fn get(&self) -> uint {
        self.a
    }
}
fn main() {
    let t = Test{a: 42};
    let m = Mutex::new(Test::new());
    println!("Getting t: {} where t.a = {}", t.get(), t.a);
    {
        let m2 = m.lock();
        println!("m2.a = {}", m2.a); // works
        //println!("m2.get() = {}", m2.get()); // error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `m2` as mutable
    }
}
```

So in this case accessing the field `m2.a` works, but calling `m2.get()` requires `m2` to be mutable although get does not mutate anything and is not declared to be mutating anything especially not `&self`.

To make this code work I could just declare `m2` with `let mut m2 = m.lock();` and everything works fine, but why do I need that mut here and is there a better way to call `m2.get()` without declaring `m2` mutable in a similar way as it works for `t` that I declare as non mutable and which still permits me to call `t.get()`.

Comment: This problem seems to not exist any longer in rust  >= 1.0. Calling `let m2 = m.lock().unwrap()` makes both print statements work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a slight limitation of the `Deref` family of traits right now - namely implementing both `Deref` and `DerefMut` for the same type right now is slightly broken due to the behavior of autoderef for methods, namely, `deref_mut` is always called, even to get `&` references.

As a result, `MutexGuard` needs to be mutable for you to call methods which require `&self`. Usually, immutable uses of `Mutex` are rare, and `RWLock`, which supports both read and write locks separately, is better suited to this use case as it allows concurrent read locks.

Comment: It actually implements `Deref` as well

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the compiler tends to prefer to call `deref_mut` over `deref` in case both are available. In your case, `deref` would suffice and work, but the implicit dereferencing machinery picks `deref_mut` instead and then complains about `m2` not being mutable.

To add to what reem said, the lock object *does* implement both, `Deref` and `DerefMut` and if you don't need a mutable borrow, you can get the immutable one by explicitly *reborrowing* it immutably:

```
println!("m2.get() = {}", (&*m2).get());
```

and if this kind of access is all you need you can also write

```
let m2 = m.lock();
let m2 = &*m2;
```

which then allows

```
println!("m2.get() = {}", m2.get());
```